# curl not downloading file inside container while building

Tags: curl, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-build

Below is my Dockerfile, no matter what option I attempted , react-dom.js file is not getting inside of the container at /app/js/ location.

```
FROM resin/rpi-raspbian:wheezy

ENV PYTHON_VERSION 2.7.13

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get -y install curl && \
        apt-get -y install vim && \
        apt-get -y install python2.7-minimal && \
        apt-get -y install python-pip && \
        apt-get -y install python-dev && \
        apt-get -y install gcc && \
            rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# RUN apt-get -y install vim


RUN mkdir -p /app/js/

VOLUME ["/app/"]

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /app/

RUN curl -sf  -o /app/js/react-dom.js -L https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js
```

Comment: What is the output ?

Comment: Since you are using `https` and the curl command actual runs inside the container, is it possible there is a problem with that? Try passing the `-k/--insecure` option to curl.

Comment: Adding parenthesis around the URL made it work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have run your dockerfile, and it just works.

I guess the image you used doesn't had quite recent ssl certificates bundle.

The image you are using (`resin/rpi-raspbian:wheezy`) had plenty of release since you used it last time !

Just pull the new image and rebuild your container and you should be good !

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out and It worked for me as well.

If you are using `docker-compose` up and have a volume set to your local in the docker-compose.yml, then if you ssh into that container to list the directory, you will be staring at your local machine's directory. Your file would still be in the image though.